# how to display absolute value on the first line and display the original value on the next line

Tags: python

I am a beginner to python programming.
I hope you guys can help me out to give me a solution to this question.

Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer and displays the absolute value of that integer on one line and then the original integer on the next line.

For example, here is a sample program run:

Enter an integer >-25

output is 25

output is -25

I have this solution in mind but it doesn't work.

```
n = abs(int(input('Enter an integer >')))

print(n)

print(-abs(n))
```

This solution would give me the correct answer as displayed above, but if i am going to try a positive integer, my solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Store the original value, not the absolute

Comment: You're right, that is what I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea by getting the user input and casting it to an integer, but don't be so quick to get the absolute value of it BEFORE saving it to a variable. If you save the user's input as they entered it, then you can just print it as your second answer. For the first part, all you need to do is get the absolute value of what they entered.

I encourage you to use the logic above to finish the problem before looking below.

```
n = int(input('Enter an integer >'))
print(abs(n))
print(n)
```